# How can we find the source of a rain water leak?

Tags: windows, leak

We have converted a garage into living space and so replaced what was the garage door with a window. Every time we have rain driving against the outside wall it comes in somewhere and leaks down through the concrete lintels and drips down inside above the window.

We have had about 3 builders now who have all done different things to try and solve our problem and nothing has worked. We have repointed the brick work outside and had it waterproofed, we have sealed the outside weep holes below the cavity tray. The roof has been examined and no water is penetrating up there so it must still somehow be coming in the outside wall above the head of the window.

How can we track down where the leak is coming from?

Comment: Some pictures of your installation would help - an overview and some detail shots. It will give people a sense of what's going on, and someone may spot something you/your contractors haven't. Just [edit] your post and drag the pics into the text edit box - they'll be uploaded & hosted for you. Or save them to imgur.com and post a link - someone will embed them for you.

Comment: Also, I've edited to actually include a question since, as the [tour] indicates, this is a Q&A site, not a general discussion forum. Open ended prompts like "I'd like to hear your experiences" don't fit well in this model.

Comment: You may need to spend some cycles with a hose. Spray one area for a while see if non it leaks, spray another area. If it is a slow leak you may need to spend decent time spraying each area, not just a splash. As you are simulating rain but in local areas, with patience you have to reveal the source area

Comment: Aren't weep holes usually designed to let water out that has got inside the frame or cavity? Sealing them can have the effect of trapping water inside where it can overflow into other places.

Comment: You might invest in a FLIR camera for your phone. I had a lower end one and upgraded to a pro model, when there is water on a heated wall it shows up quite well, I found an attic roof leak that was traveling down the rafter quite a way before coming to the bottom side the FLIR camera picked it up quickly, they can also be used to find loose connections , leaks in duct work. I liked my base line model enough to upgrade.